# How can I create application that can connects to SQL server and perform CRUD operation?

Tags: android, sql-server, web-services

Can anybody suggest me how to connect SQL server with Android? I need to create, read, update, delete data in SQL server from Android UI.

If anybody provide me source that will be greatly helpful for me.

Comment: There is another way if you want you can directly connect to sql server and perform your action from android.Condtion your mobile and database must be in same network.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the Database driver in to your project and regular jdbc code for that. But i suppose this is not a good practice. Instead use SAOP or  REST webservice with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Create a RESTFul webservice with JSON and implement all your CRUD operations in that webservice. It is not a good practice to directly connect to a database from mobile devices because then you are exposing your backend to the outside world.

Check the [link](http://guruparan.blog.com/2012/03/30/connecting-android-to-sql-server-via-wcf-using-json-part-1/) for actual implementation. [Here](http://anindita9.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/consuming-sql-serversql-azure-data-in-windows-phone-7-1-android-through-odata-wcf-data-services-entity-frameworks/) is a more detailed example.